# Get the class names in the order of rendering in the UI

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In the below code,common class name  is given for each div element.

```
<div id="category_9" class="list_item" data-item_ids="[38]"</div>
<div id="category_2" class="list_item" data-item_ids="[26,39]"</div>
<div id="category_4" class="list_item" data-item_ids="[25,34,12,4,14]"</div>
<div id="category_8" class="list_item" data-item_ids="[37,6,78,3]"</div>
<div id="category_1" class="list_item" data-item_ids="[20,33]"</div>
```

I need to retrieve the class name with the above order itself with ids in the order:

**'category_9' , 'category_2' ,'category_4' ,'category_8' ,'category_1'**

I used the below code , but getting the classes in ascending order of digit in the id,like:

'category_1', 'category_2, 'category_4, 'category_8, 'category_9

```
grouped_items = {} 
$('.list_item').each ->
  group_id = $(this).attr('id').split('category_').join('')
  grouped_items[group_id] = $(this).data('item_ids')
return grouped_items
```

How is it possible.Please help

Thanks

Comment: You can push them in `key` ,`value` pair .

Answer (score 1):

`$('.list_item').each` will regard the doom order of elements, so i assume you have problem with `grouped_items as object` which sort order of insert elements.

use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map?retiredLocale=vi) instead

```js
grouped_items = new Map
$('.list_item').each ->
  group_id = $(this).attr('id').split('category_').join('')
  grouped_items.set(group_id, $(this).data('item_ids'))
return grouped_items
```